# How to import a MySQLdump into a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a MySQLdump generated by PHPMyAdmin, and I need to import it into a Postgresql database, but I dont know if it's even possible. I've seen people recommending pgloader but seens a little confusing on how to do it. Also I'm on windows if its relevant at all.

I only need the tables, so I'm not concerned about the data in the old or in the new database.

It's not that big too, only 84 tables. But big enough for me to write it.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't give you specifics, but if the schema dump is just sql statements you should be able to import them into postgres without too much trouble. You may have to edit the dump if there are mysql/postgres differences that get in the way. You can just pipe sql commands into psql, including  new table definitions.

Comment: I have added an answer, you can try that

Comment: @dschultz I tried manually at first, but there were too many little differences, atleast in my base, so It would be annoying to work it all out. I'm doing it from scratch anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/).

You need to [install](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) it, and then run a simple lisp script (`script.lisp`) with the following 3 lines:

```
/* content of the script.lisp */
LOAD DATABASE
FROM mysql://dbuser@localhost/dbname
INTO postgresql://dbuser@localhost/dbname;


/*run this in the terminal*/
pgloader script.lisp
```

And after that, your PostgreSQL DB will have all of the information that you had in your MySQL DB.

Comment: You might need to use `dbuser:pass@yourdbhost/dbname` for the connection string, and the username, password, dbhost can be different for MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Though I wont need it anymore since we changing pretty much every table. I missed this documentation link while looking around for how to install it, thus my confusion about pgloader.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of resources to do this. None of them are simple.

- `pgloader` which you mentioned is among the many tools listed on this page:  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL
- MySQLdump is supposed to have an option `--compatible=postgres` but don't rely on that. It makes some changes to its output, but not enough to be fully compatible with PostgreSQL syntax.
- Another option is to dump tables to CSV files with `mysqldump --tables` instead of dumping to SQL format. Then you can bulk-load the CSV files one by one with the `COPY` statement in PostgreSQL.

If your MySQL database contains views or stored routines (procedures, functions, triggers, or events), then in general those can't be converted by any tool. The PostgreSQL language for stored routines is too different from MySQL. You must just start over and code routines in PostgreSQL that do equivalent logic, but coded in a way more idiomatic for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the options, pgloader is the easiest for me after going through the docs, but its good to know the alternatives. It was not that complicated base too, just some create tables and constraints with little to no logic.